# Results not displayed with click event (Angular)

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, frontend, mouseclick-event

I'm new to Stackoverflow and to Angular. I'm writing a frontend app (an ecommerce) in Angular. I binded a click event to a button of a mat-menu in order to have the following behavior: when I click on the button I want to display the products of the category that has been clicked. For example, if I click the button "Make-up" I want that all the products with category "Make-up" will be displayed. The problem is that when I click on the button nothing is displayed on the browser, but I suppose that the logic of the app works because if I open the console of the browser the producs of the selected category are printed out.

product.component.html:

```html
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="categoryFilter('Make-up')"> Make-up</button>
    ... 
</mat-menu>
```

product.component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-product',
    templateUrl: './product.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./product.component.css'] })

export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
    public products: Product[] = [];
    public product!: Product;

    constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }
    
    ngOnInit() {
        this.getProducts();
    }

    public getProducts(): void{
        this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(
            (response: Product[]) => {
                this.products= response;
            },
            (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                alert(error.message);
            }
        );
    }
  
    public categoryFilter(category: string): void{
        this.productService.getProductsByCategory(category).subscribe(
            (response: void) => {
                console.log(response);
            },
            (error. HttpErrorResponse)=>{
                alert(error.message);
            }
        )
    } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have missed binding the response to a property, and then using that property to display the data on your browser.

I don't know the response type, ***for demo purposes let's say it's a string***.

First, you'll need to create a property just like you created `public product!: Product;` we'll call it `categoryName: string`

In the click event, you'll have to bind this property with your response, hence it should look something like this:

```
 public categoryFilter(category: string): void{
        this.productService.getProductsByCategory(category).subscribe(
            (response: string) => {
                this.categoryName = response;
                console.log(response);
            },
            (error. HttpErrorResponse)=>{
                alert(error.message);
            }
        )
  }
```

Now You'll have to bind that `categoryName` in your HTML so that it can be displayed. You can use Angular's text interpolation which uses curly brackets {{}}  to display string values in the HTML.
Hence your HTML will look like this:

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="categoryFilter('Make-up')"> {{ categoryName }} </button>
    ... 
</mat-menu>
```

I advise you to read Angular's Guide as you proceed further.

Angular's text interpolation: https://angular.io/guide/interpolation

Comment: Thanks! I solved the problem following your suggestions! The type of response must be Product[], in my case. And then the only thing to do is to add, to the html code, a table that displays the products obtained.